# No preview option for files or images uploaded through PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have created a powerApp form to upload images or files to SharePoint library. It is able to upload the files to library but when I click on the file or image to open it then I get the error in browser that the file has no review available although when I upload a file directly to library then that file opens without any issue.

Comment: Can you please share some sample code you followed for this. There are limitation with some of the controls to upload files or images.

Comment: I wonder how did you upload the file to document library directly.. cause To my  knowledge there is no official way to upload or edit document library items. How did you manage to upload the files to doc library?

Answer (score 0):

How did you set PowerApps form to upload file to document library?

Uploading files directly to SharePoint library is not available within PowerApps currently.

As a workaround, we can use Microsoft Flow and PowerApps to upload file to SharePoint Online document library, you can check the article:

[PowerApps upload file to SharePoint Online document library using Microsoft Flow](https://www.sharepointsky.com/powerapps-upload-file-to-sharepoint-document-library/)

Comment: I have followed the same. But the file preview is not coming.

Comment: Same issue here, there is no previewing of images copied to SharePoint from Power Automate.